# Cpanel is not giving me option to change the root directory for one of my domains

Tags: linux, laravel, server, centos, cpanel

I need to change the root directory for one of my domains,

But in my cpanel i dont find any options, just hard cores of system, but i have very basic knowledge about systems and servers.

How i can change that directory as easy as possible? I just need to change something because im gonna install laravel, and i want to change the public html to the public of laravel.

I was looking for the file that has the apache config, but it says like "the current config doesnt need to be changed or updated, bacause can be overryde", so i tought in Cpanel maybe i got an option for this.

Thanks, By the way i got an VPS, not shared. Using CENTOS 7.9.

Thanks and good night ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cPanel, you can't change main domain directory/document root. If you want to change the document root, just change the main domain to another/random domain. Then add the domain that you want to change the root directory as [addon domain](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/addon-domains/)

It's not recommended overriding Apache config. It's may break your system. WHM/cPanel exists to manage domains without a system admin knowledge

Comment: So i should openWHM (root cpanel) and go to domains? i dont see the option fr domains..

Comment: to change domain, on WHM  go to `List accounts` menu then select an account and click modify account. You can change domain on that form.

Comment: to add domain, just open cPanel and go to `Addon Domains` menu then input the domain name and document root

Comment: if i add a domain, it doesnt work, give me a DNS Error, i would like to delete my current domain, and just create new one ( with same name) and give the new directory

Comment: before add a domain, did you changed the main domain?

Comment: No, just want to create new domain and give a new directory, but i cannot even delete that main domain, because it delete all the subdomains

Comment: if you change the main domain, that would not delete all subdomain file/directory, so you can add all subdomains again later,

Comment: I created new subdomain ( sub {web} domain {pjinmobiliaria.com}) == web.pjinmobiliaria.com , and i get that error " DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN "
By the way, i need to configure something? domain name or something, to use that new sub domain?, i just created that one new with correct directory but doesnt work, web.pjinmobiliaria.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229098/discussion-between-muhammad-dyas-yaskur-and-juliian68).

Answer (score 1):

Do you try change this using console in Centos?
maybe will be better using console and open the file that contain the directory root

Comment: As Muhammed says "It's not recommended overriding Apache config. It's may break your system. WHM/cPanel exists to manage domains without a system admin knowledge"